# Problem to load an image dataset in Google colab from google drive

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I try to load an image dataset (a zip file) in my drive using google colab.
I try with this code:

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf

dataset_url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/id_my_drive?usp=sharing/"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file("dataset", origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
dataset = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(dataset.glob('**/*.jpg')))
print('nr img: ', image_count)
```

but when I count the elements in the data_dir it give 0. Why?
The code it seems correct according official Tensorflow example (https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/load_data/images.ipynb).
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easiest way to do it actually by mounting your Google drive in your colab.

Step 1: Mount Google drive in Colab

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
```

Step 2: Unzip the zip file

```
!unzip -u -q "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset_images.zip"
```

Step 3: Read all the images from the dataset folder, Give path to the extracted folder.

```
import glob
for image_path in glob.glob("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset_images/*.jpg"):
    print(image_path)
```